# Cascading select data binding

Tags: angularjs

First look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3em8rz3v/35/)

JavaScript:

```
function CountryCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.filters = {};
    $scope.categories = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Company",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "About",
        "children": [{
            "id": 6,
            "title": "Company profile",
            "children": [],
            "isRoot": false
        }],
        "isRoot": false
    } ..
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="CountryCntrl">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>Filter by:</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-if="cat.isRoot==true">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select ng-if="cat.isRoot==true" class="form-control" ng-model="filters.rootCat" ng-options="sub_cat.title for sub_cat in cat.children track by sub_cat.id">
                            <option value="">level 1 - {{$index}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="filters[cat.id]" ng-options="sub_sub_cat.title for sub_sub_cat in filters.rootCat.children track by sub_sub_cat.id">
                            <option value="">level 2 - {{$index}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not able to display the options of the select of the second level only, related to the first level.

In my fiddle you can see that you change the value of "level 1-0" the select below "level 2 - 0" is correctly populated but is `binded` the "level 2 - 6" too...

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an ng-repeat in which you use the same object as model for each item repeated, which means they will conflict and affect each other.

The simplest solution is probably to change `filters.rootCat` to `filters['rootCat'+$index]`.

That way you ensure that each column of dropdowns have their own model.